# join 2 same almost same function into 1

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function showRole(str,x)
        {
            if (str=="")
              {
              document.getElementById("txtHintrole"+x+"").innerHTML="";
              return;
              } 
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
              {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
              xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
              }
            else
              {// code for IE6, IE5
              xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
              }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
              {
              if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                {
                document.getElementById("txtHintrole"+x+"").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
              }

            xmlhttp.open("GET","http://localhost/tes/index.php/form/role/"+str,true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
```

```
function showUser(str,x)
        {
            if (str=="")
              {
              document.getElementById("txtHint"+x+"").innerHTML="";
              return;
              } 
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
              {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
              xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
              }
            else
              {// code for IE6, IE5
              xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
              }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
              {
              if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
                {
                document.getElementById("txtHint"+x+"").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
              }

            xmlhttp.open("GET","http://localhost/tes/index.php/form/hint/"+str,true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
```

can i join this 2 function into 1
because i need both of them to show data
and i dont know how to set 2 function with this

> newcell.childNodes[0].setAttribute("onchange","showUser(this.value,"+xx+");");

Comment: It's hard to say much without seeing the functions.  Do you get errors on your console?

Comment: Can you please attach the (relevant) HTML code as well.

Comment: i have edited my post
i cannot post it before this web said my post contain code not a code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing you want to call two functions on `onchange`. Try this:

```
newcell.childNodes[0].setAttribute("onchange",function(){
    showUser(this.value,"+xx+");
    secondFunction();
});
```

or since you tagged this jQuery, do it the jQuery way:

```
$(newcell.childNodes[0]).change(function(){
    showUser(this.value,"+xx+");
    secondFunction();
});
```

Comment: i have tried it manually
and i got error because both of my function is use to show data
and they have almost same just a little bit different

and i think i want to join that 2 function into 1
so i just need to call 1 function